# Configure VSCode's PowerShell extension to show a script stacktrace by default for script-terminating errors

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, debugging, powershell-7

The default output of **script-terminating errors** that appears in the integrated console of VSCode's PowerShell extension, is not very helpful for debugging. It only shows the error message and the line where the error originated from (in case of module functions, not even the actual line, but just the caller's location).

What I actually want to see is a full **script stacktrace** in addition to the error message, **without having to add exception-handling code** to every script.

**Example:**

```bash
Function Test-Me { 
    Test-You
}

Function Test-You {
    throw 'foo error'
}

Test-Me
```

**Actual output:**

```
Exception: C:\Test.ps1:6:2
Line |
   6 |      throw 'foo error'
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | foo error
```

**Desired output:**

```
Exception: C:\Test.ps1:6:2
Line |
   6 |      throw 'foo error'
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | foo error

at Test-You, C:\Test.ps1: line 6
at Test-Me, C:\Test.ps1: line 2
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Test.ps1: line 10
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
```

While an output like this can be trivially achieved by exception-handling code as follows, it would be too much hassle to add this boilerplate code to each small code snippet I need to debug.

```bash
try {
    Test-Me
}
catch {
    $_ | Out-Host
    Write-Debug "`n$($_.ScriptStackTrace)" -Debug
}
```

While there is a simple way to (also) show a script stacktrace, it causes an error output that is too messy, showing way more information than needed:

```bash
# At the top of the script
$ErrorView = 'DetailedView'
```

Is there a way to configure VSCode's PowerShell extension to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a "**launch.json**" file. This works well for me, because I keep all my small snippets within a single folder.

1. Open VSCode from the folder's context menu or launch VSCode normally and open the folder from the *File* > *Open Folder* menu item.
2. Open the *Run and Debug* tab.
3. Click on the *create a launch.json file* link and choose *PowerShell*, then *Launch Current File*. This creates a default *launch.json* file.
4. Modify the `script` property to wrap the script call in an exception handler. My customized *launch.json* looks like this:

   ```bash
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "PowerShell: Launch Current File",
               "type": "PowerShell",
               "request": "launch",
               "script": "try { & ${file} } catch { $_ | Out-Host; Write-Debug -Debug (\"`n\" + $_.ScriptStackTrace) }",
               "args": []
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Save *launch.json*, it should be automatically saved in a *.vscode* sub folder.

After following these steps, every script launched via <kbd>F5</kbd>, produces the desired output when a script-terminating error occurs. You can even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on a line of the stacktrace to directly jump to the referred code location.

[image: VSCode terminal]