# Powershell: how to get full stack trace from Write-Error

Tags: powershell, error-handling

How do I get a full stack trace for `Write-Error` messages?

E.g. the following code

```
function a {
    write-error "error"
}

function b {
    a
}

function c {
    b
}

c
```

Outputs only last stack frame:

```
PS C:\> .\_test.ps1
a : error
At C:\_test.ps1:6 char:5
+     a
+     ~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,a
```

Comment: If you happen to use VSCode this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77496819/7571258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the `ScriptStackTrace` property on the associated error record:

```
function a {
    write-error "error"
}

function b {
    a
}

function c {
    b
}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {
    c
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Encountered error. Script stack trace:"
    Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
}
```

---

In PowerShell 7 you can also configure the `DetailedView` `$ErrorView` preference to show the script stack trace in error output by default:

```
$ErrorView = 'DetailedView'
```